# JDBC Connection from MySQL database to Spreadsheet very slow

Tags: mysql, database, google-apps-script, google-sheets, jdbc

I have created this script to push the data from my MySQL database to google spreadsheet.
Now, to be updated, I have created a trigger every 5 minutes to run the script, but strangely when I see the executions of the trigger, it run approximately every 40 minutes.
The run of the script is approximately 2 minutes and so after this it push the data in the spreadsheet.

Is there something wrong with the script?

And how can I enforce the update duration that I have established in the trigger?

```
var MAXROWS = 100000
var SEEKWELL_J_SHORT_DATES = { day: "yyyy-MM-dd", month: "yyyy-MM", year: "yyyy", dayNum: "dd", monthNum: "MM", yearNum: "yyyy", week: "W" }
var SEEKWELL_J_TIMEZONE = "UTC"
var HOST = 'xxx'
var PORT = 'xxx'
var USERNAME = 'xxx'
var PASSWORD = 'xxx'
var DATABASE = 'xxx'
var DB_TYPE = 'mysql'

function runSql(query, options) {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    //var sheet = doc.getActiveSheet();
    var sheet = doc.getSheets()[0];
    var sheetName = sheet.getName();
    //var cell = doc.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
    var cell = sheet.getRange('a1');
    var activeCellRow = cell.getRow();
    var activeCellCol = cell.getColumn();
    try {
        var fullConnectionString = 'jdbc:' + DB_TYPE + '://' + HOST + ':' + PORT
        var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(fullConnectionString, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        console.log('query :', query)
        var stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.execute('USE ' + DATABASE);
        var start = new Date();
        var stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.setMaxRows(MAXROWS);
        var rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e, e.lineNumber);
        Browser.msgBox(e);
        return false
    }
    var results = [];
    cols = rs.getMetaData();
    console.log("cols", cols)
    var colNames = [];
    var colTypes = {};
    for (i = 1; i <= cols.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        var colName = cols.getColumnLabel(i)
        colTypes[colName] = { type: cols.getColumnTypeName(i), loc: i }
        colNames.push(colName);
    }
    var rowCount = 1;
    results.push(colNames);
    while (rs.next()) {
        curRow = rs.getMetaData();
        rowData = [];
        for (i = 1; i <= curRow.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            rowData.push(rs.getString(i));
        }
        results.push(rowData);
        rowCount++;
    }
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    conn.close();
    console.log('results', results)
    var colCount = results[0].length
    var rowCount = results.length
    var comment = "Updated on: " + (new Date()) + "\n" + "Query:\n" + query
    if (options.omitColumnNames) {
        results = results.slice(1)
        rowCount -= 1
    }
    if (options.clearColumns && sheet.getLastRow() > 0) {
        var startCellRange = sheet.getRange(startCell)
        sheet.getRange(startCellRange.getRow(), startCellRange.getColumn(), sheet.getLastRow(), colCount).clearContent();
    }
    if (options.clearSheet) {
        var startCellRange = sheet.getRange(startCell)
        sheet.clear({ contentsOnly: true });
    }
    //sheet.getRange(activeCellRow, activeCellCol, rowCount, colCount).clearContent();
    sheet.getRange(activeCellRow, activeCellCol, rowCount, colCount).setValues(results);
    var cell = sheet.getRange(activeCellRow, activeCellCol)
    cell.clearNote()
    cell.setNote(comment);
    sheet.setActiveRange(sheet.getRange(activeCellRow + rowCount + 1, activeCellCol))
    console.log('query success!, rows = ', rowCount - 1)
}

function runSqlFromSheet() {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sql = doc.getRange('query!A1').getDisplayValue();
    var options = {}
    Logger.log('sql;', sql)
    runSql(sql, options)
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us: does the script finish promptly when it runs, or does it run for many minutes?  And what query do you use (from cell query!A1) ?

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: The general answer is to replace setValue() and getValue() with setValues() and getValues() to get and set data all and one time and move the data around in 2d arrays.  It normally improves performance by about 10X. But JDBC is slow

Comment: @Cooper in my code there is no setValue() or getValue() in order to replace with setValues() and getValues(). Which row do you mean? Than, in order to reach my goal, there is an alternative to JDBC?

Comment: Use `console.time()` to figure out which part takes the most time and post it here.

Comment: @TheMaster How to do that?

Comment: Search the official documentation. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for free resources and more details.